# Integration of a cohomology class over a homology class.

Tags: integration, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Can anyone explain to me what it is said in the following article : http://indico.ictp.it/event/a06114/material/0/0.pdf , page : $3$, by Mr. Aroldo Kaplan :

The paragraph says :

> **Stokes** :
>   $$ \int_M d \omega = \int_{ \partial M }\omega $$
>   implies :
>   $$ d \omega = 0 \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ \int_{ \mathrm{boundary} } \omega = 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \mathrm{and} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \partial M = 0 \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ \int_M \mathrm{exact} = 0 $$
>   so, defining :
>
> $ H^k ( X ) = \dfrac{ \{ \omega \in \bigwedge^k \ : \ d \omega = 0 \} }{ \{ \omega \in \bigwedge^{k} \ : \ \omega = d \phi \} } = \dfrac{ \mathrm{closed} }{ \mathrm{exact} } $ , $ \ H_k ( X ) = \dfrac{ \{ M \subset X \ : \ \partial M = 0 \} }{ \{ M \subset X \ : \ M = \partial N \} } = \dfrac{ \mathrm{cycles} }{ \mathrm{boundaries} } $
>
> the bilinear (function?):
>   $$ H^k ( X ) \times H_k ( X ) \to \mathbb{R}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  ( [ \omega ] , [M] ) = \int_M \omega $$
>   ( = flux of $ \omega $ through $ M $ ) is well defined.

So, I still do not understand why:
$$ H^k ( X ) \times H_k ( X ) \to \mathbb{R}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  ( [ \omega ] , [M] ) = \int_M \omega $$
is well defined.
Can you explain to me that please ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What are you unclear about? Integrating a closed form or over a boundary gives $0$, so the integral $\int_M \omega$ depends only on $[M]$ and $[\omega]$.

Comment: @anomaly : When is the bilinear well defined ? When we don't integrate a closed form as well as when we don't integrate over a boundary ? In this case : $ [ \omega ] \not \in H^k ( X ) $ and $ [ M ] \not \in H_k (X) $. I don't really understand that clearly.  :-)

Comment: Bah, I meant exact rather than closed above.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but it sounds like you don't understand the definition of $H_*$ and $H^*$.

Comment: I understand the definition of $ H_* $ and $ H^* $. $ [M ] \in H_* (X) $, for instance means $ M $ is a cycle but not a boundary, and $ \omega \in H^k (X ) $ means $ \omega $ is closed but not exact, right ? but, i still not undestand your first answer.

Comment: A boundary still has a homology class- the zero class. Likewise the zero cohomology class is the equivalence class of all exact forms. You can say e.g. that a representative for a nonzero cohomology class is closed but not exact.

Comment: @Lina45: No, that's not correct. Look up the definition of the quotient of two vector spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's prove that $([\omega],[M])=([\omega+d\phi],[M])$.

indeed, $([\omega+d\phi],[M])-([\omega],[M])=\int_M d\phi=\int_{\partial M}\phi=0$, because $M$ is a cycle.

secondly, let's prove that $([\omega],[M])=([\omega],[M+\partial N])$.

indeed, $([\omega],[M+\partial N])-([\omega],[M])=\int_{\partial N}\omega=\int_N d\omega=0$, because $\omega$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you very much SIr.  :)